# WebView has been removed from React Native error after installing QRCode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a new project and project was run without any problem but after i installed QRCode by this command:

```
 npm install react-native-qrcode --save
```

and then import that:

```
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';
```

I am getting this error:

WebView has been removed from React Native

I've never installed or used WebView.
How can i solve this?

Comment: You can use another module to Generate QR code.
Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64875511/6717123

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

Edit node_modules/react-native-qrcode/lib/Canvas.js

> var {
>       View,
>       WebView,
>       Platform
>   } = require('react-native');

To

> import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
>   var {
>       View,
>       // WebView,
>       Platform
>   } = require('react-native');

Found here:
https://github.com/cssivision/react-native-qrcode/issues/80

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is that to remove the qrcode package and try with another one.

I personally suggest **react-native-qrcode-svg**. It's the best one for generating QR codes in react.

For install react-native-svg,

```
npm install react-native-svg --save
react-native link react-native-svg
npm install react-native-qrcode-svg --save
```

**Examples**

```
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

//Simple usage, defaults for all but the value
render() {
  return (
    <QRCode
      value="https://github.com/codemaker2015"
    />
  );
};
```