# React Native - QR code generator size restrictions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qr-code

I am trying to make a QR code generator that stores multiple values, but I am exceeding the character count. After further research, I found that 35 characters, which is equivalent to a micro QR code, even tho it displays a full-size QR code. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
I am also interested in passing `JSON` or an `array` to the QR code but haven't found anything useful about it on the internet.

My code:

[image: QRcodeGenerator]

Comment: Embed your code as TEXT...

Answer (score 2):

You can use another module to generate QR code. Seems there is no character restriction.

another answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64875511/6717123